# 'serviceWorker' in navigator is false

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

Iam working on site which is running on http://local.mydomain.com (virtual host)

And it gives me `false` when i check `'serviceWorker' in navigator` So i cant test my service worker locally.

Also i have tried to put the url in to [chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure](http://chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure) but it didnt solve the problem.

Is there any workaround to fix this?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but it gives me `false` when i tried to `console.log('serviceWorker' in navigator);` in the console,if im on `https` it gives me `true` if not `false` even if i put the url to the `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there's none.

[The SW will only work under HTTPS or at localhost](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers#you_need_https).

Since the later option is left this way specifically for development, I'd advise to use it.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense, use https or else use localhost